# Issue with Flash Player 10

Tags: flash

Some times when the URL is clicked it navigates to the videopage, but I am hearing audio but not seeing any video. Why might this be?

I am using the latest version of Flash Player 10. The SWF in question was created in Flash 9 (CS2).

```
var s1 = new SWFObject("flvplayer.swf","single","560","400","7");
                                                            ===
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2528961/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this issue might be because of Flash version compatibility. You may be using a lower versioned player for a higher versioned .swf file.

Check your flash player version or get the [latest one](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/) from adobe